# radio button cannot empty

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code for radio button. I want add condition, when one radio button not selected by user, then it will come out warning there is data empty. When complete, it will count sum.

```
<form action="" method="post">
Player 1:
male <input type="radio" name="gender[1]" value="1">
female <input type="radio" name="gender[1]" value="2">
<br>
Player 2:
male <input type="radio" name="gender[2]" value="1">
female <input type="radio" name="gender[2]" value="2">
<br>
Player 3:
male <input type="radio" name="gender[3]" value="1">
female <input type="radio" name="gender[3]" value="2"> 
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $sum=0;
    if (isset($_POST['gender']))
    {
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        foreach ($gender as $value)
            {
               $sum=$sum+$value;
            }
            echo $sum;

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'you did not choose any genders';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `echo $_POST['gender']` above `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, is your current code not working? Also, do head over to [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look :)

Comment: my code work, but when I only select one, it keep count sum. When there is one data empty it will not count sum

Comment: So your code works when you have only selected one? and I lost you there.

Comment: yes, work if i select one or all three data, But I want add condition I cannot select one or two, if I not select then come out warning I must select all male / female

Comment: Why don't you replace the `else { ...}` with `if (count($_POST['gender']) < 3) { echo 'you did not choose any genders' }`?

Comment: Why do you not use Javascript to check that allready client side? Shure you have to do it on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all radio buttons are selected, `count($_POST['gender'])` would be 3. So just replace

```
else
{
    echo 'you did not choose any genders';
}
```

with

```
if (count($_POST['gender']) < 3) { 
    echo 'you did not choose any genders';
}
```

Comment: Not `count($sum)` because that can be anywhere between 0 and 6. You need to do `count($_POST['gender'])`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you can write

```
if(!$_POST['gender']) echo ....;
```

or, if you want to check single positions

```
if(!$_POST['gender'][0] && !$_POST['gender'][1] && !$_POST['gender'][2]) echo ...;
```